# cgroup blkio files cannot be written

Tags: io, linux-kernel, operating-system, cgroups

I'm trying to control I/O bandwidth by using **cgroup blkio** controller.

Cgroup has been setup and mounted successfully, i.e. calling `grep cgroup /proc/mounts`

returns:

```
....
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,relatime,blkio 0 0
...
```

I then make a new folder in the `blkio` folder and write to the file `blkio.throttle.read_bps_device`, as follows:

```
1. mkdir user1; cd user1
2. echo "8:5 10485760" > blkio.throtlle.read_bps_device
----> echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

My device major:minor number is correct from using `df -h` and `ls -l /dev/sda5` for the storage device.

And I can still write to file that requires no device major:minor number, such as `blkio.weight` (but the same error is thrown for `blkio.weigth_device`)

Any idea why I got that error?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure which flavour/version of Linux you are using, on RHEL 6.x kernels, this was did not work for some reason, however it worked when I compiled on a custom kernel on RHEL and on other Fedora versions without any issues.

To check if supported on your kernel, run `lssubsys -am | grep blkio`. Check the path if you can file the file `blkio.throttle.read_bps_device`

However, here is an example of how you can do it persistently, set a cgroups to limit the program not to exceed more than 1 Mibi/s:

1. Get the MARJOR:MINOR device number from `/proc/partitions`

> ```
>    `cat /proc/partitions | grep vda` 
>      major minor  #blocks  name
>      252        0   12582912 vda  --> this is the primary disk (with MAJOR:MINOR -> 8:0)
> ```

2. Now if you want to limit your program to 1mib/s (convert the value to bytes/s) as follows. => 1MiB/s => 1024 kiB/1MiB * 1024 B/s = 1048576 Bytes/sec
3. Edit /etc/cgconfig.conf and add the following entry

> ```
> group ioload {
>   blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "252:0 1048576" 
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Edit /etc/cgrules.conf

> *: blkio   ioload

5. Restart the required services

> ```
> `chkconfig {cgred,cgconfig} on;`
> `service {cgred,cgconfig} restart`
> ```

Refer: [blkio-controller.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt)

hope this helps!

Comment: The problem was that I used /dev/sda5 as the device name, while in fact the *physical device name* (as opposed to the partitioned, logical device) must be use. It now works when I specify the <major>:<minor> id of /dev/sda

Comment: The `lssubsys` command was pretty useful to understand whether the feature was supported by my kernel.  Thanks!